# Working around the limitations of extension traits

Tags: iterator, rust, traits

The pattern of having an object-safe trait `Foo` and a (potentially unsafe) extension trait `FooExt` implemented for all instances of `Foo` seems to become standard now.

https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/445

This is a problem for me in the case of `Iterator<A>`, as I have a library that overrides the default method `IteratorExt#last()` of the old iterator trait (the underlying library has an efficient implementation of `last()`). This in now impossible, because for any `A`, there will always be a conflicting trait implementation of `IteratorExt`, the one that `libcore` already provides for all `Iterator<A>`.

`` iterator.rs:301:1: 306:2 error: conflicting implementations for trait `core::iter::IteratorExt` [E0119] ``

```
iterator.rs:301 impl<'a, K: Key> iter::IteratorExt<Vec<u8>> for ValueIterator<'a,K,Vec<u8>> {
iterator.rs:302   fn last(&mut self) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
iterator.rs:303      self.seek_last();
iterator.rs:304      Some(self.value())
iterator.rs:305   }
iterator.rs:306 }
...
```

Now, as far as I see, I have two options:

- have my own trait and my own `last()` implementation. That would mean it conflicts if `IteratorExt` is imported unless carefully used. This also has the danger accidentally using an inefficient version of `last()` if the version from `IteratorExt` is used. I'd loose convenient access to `IteratorExt`.
- have my own trait and name the method differently (`seek_last()`). Disadvantage: I ask the user to learn vocabulary and to always favor my method over that provided by `IteratorExt`. Same problem: I'd like to avoid accidental usage of `last()`.

Is there any other, better, solution I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `rustc 0.13.0-nightly (8bca470c5 2014-12-08 00:12:30 +0000)` defining `last()` as an inherent method on your type should work.

```
#[deriving(Copy)]
struct Foo<T> {t: T}

impl<T> Iterator<T> for Foo<T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> { None }
}

// this does not work
// error: conflicting implementations for trait `core::iter::IteratorExt` [E0119]
// impl<T> IteratorExt<T> for Foo<T> {
//    fn last(mut self) -> Option<T> { None }
//}

// but this currently does
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn last(mut self) -> Option<T> { Some(self.t) }
}


fn main() {
    let mut t = Foo{ t: 3u };
    println!("{}", t.next())
    println!("{}", t.last()) // last has been "shadowed" by our impl
    println!("{}", t.nth(3)) // other IteratorExt methods are still available
}
```

Since you're not supposed to use Extension traits as generic bounds (but just to provide additional methods), this should theoretically work for your scenario, as you can have your own type and its `impl` in the same crate.

Users of your type will use the inherent `last` method instead of the one on `IteratorExt` but still be able to use the other methods on `IteratorExt`.

Comment: I cannot get this working with `rustc 0.13.0-nightly (193390d0e 2014-12-11 22:56:54 +0000)`. Doesn't override the method, warns for `dead_code`. I like that as a solution, though.

Comment: Scratch that, I didn't make the method public to use it in another crate. It works with `pub fn last(...)`.

Comment: Will this generally work in generic code that consumes such a type (with Iterator bound) and possibly lives in another crate?

Comment: @sellibitze does it work today? Yes. Will it work in Rust 1.0? Who knows... The traits reform RFC, [in the section on method resolution](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0048-traits.md#method-resolution) states explicitly that the priority given today to implicit methods might be revised in the future

Answer (score 0):

`last` should be moved to `Iterator`, rather than `IteratorExt`.

`IteratorExt` is needed when using `Box<Iterator>` objects, to allow calling generic methods on them (e.g. `map`), because you can't put a generic method in a vtable. However, `last` isn't generic, so it can be put in `Iterator`.

Comment: This could be a solution to this specific problem, but the question is asking about a general solution for extension traits.